# could not load oramts.dll

Tags: c#, oracle

even i've installed Oracle Services for Microsoft Transaction Server with oracle client but still having the below error:
 - Fail to load oramts.dll

I've googled the error lot, all I've found aims to install the transaction server for oracle
but it does not work. i'm using oracle client 11g 11.2

is there any other configurations required?

Comment: Have you tried Googling your error message and going through some of the results to see if one of those solutions works? If so, what have you tried?

Comment: _Is there any other configurations reguired?_ Your question isn't clear. Show your effort first.. Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: I've edited the question to list what I've found

Comment: how does it "not work"? read [so-hints](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints), [whathaveyoutried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) or [sscce](http://sscce.org) (The key here would be: *Imagine You're Trying To Answer The Question*)

Comment: the same error always returned  I've both the oracle db and oracle client in the same server the db also has oramts installed with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this kind of problem before, usually uninstall existing Oracle client and then install oracle with Oracle Services For Microsoft Transaction Server checkbox checked helps.